# Using Javascript to select a value from a Html Select box

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys I am using JavaScript to select a specific value(option) from the html select form tag, but whenever I call my JavaScript function I get a single message repeating for all the choices I want to select.
Ex: If I choose to select 'Rabbit' from the list of options and then display a message saying 'Rabbit chosen'; the message will display for each option/value selected.

Here is my JavaScript Code:

```
    var element = document.getElementById('choices').value;

    function SelectElement() {    
      if (element = 'Rabbit') {
          alert("Rabbit Selected");
      }
      else if (element = 'Wall') {
          alert("Wall Selected");
      }
      else if (element = 'Arrow') {
          alert("Arrow Selected");
      }      
   }
```

Here is my html code:

```
 <form>
     <select id="choices" >
        <option>Rabbit</option>
        <option>Wall</option>
        <option>Arrow</option>
     </select>

     <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SelectElement()"/>
 </form>
```

Can you smart guys please help me????

Comment: You have made mistake in your if statement, Do it double equal and it will fix your issue.

Comment: hmm.. didn't work for me.

Comment: I used the comparison operator, but nothing happens when I click submit.

Comment: can you take that var element inside the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A.** You should fetch the value each time before calling the function and then check it otherwise your `element` variable won't refresh at all.

**B.** To compare two values you should use `==`, `=` is an assignment operator.

```
   function SelectElement() { 
      var element = document.getElementById('choices').value;   
      if (element == 'Rabbit') {
          alert("Rabbit Selected");
      }  
   }
```

(As your question is not much clear) if you just want to alert the selected value for every option clicked, just do:

```
  function SelectElement() { 
      var element = document.getElementById('choices').value;   
      alert(element+" Selected");
   }
```

This is basic string concatenation.

Comment: Sorry, I missed everything after A.  I removed it.

Comment: @heisenberg it okay :)

Comment: nice one @void but how do I fetch the value each time before calling the function so that my variable element refreshes?

Comment: I used the comparison operator, but nothing happens when I click submit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a something called `selected == true` or `false` in a "select" tag. 
You could write in HTML :

```
<form>
  <select id="choices">
    <option id="Rabbit">Rabbit</option>
    <option id="Wall">Wall</option>
    <option id="Arrow">Arrow</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button onclick="TakeElement()">Click</button>
```

You could write in javascript:

```
   var ra = document.getElementById('Rabbit');
    var wa = document.getElementById('Wall');  
var ar = document.getElementById('Arrow');

   function TakeElement() {
      if (ra.selected == true) {
        alert("Rabbit is selected");
      }
      if (wa.selected == true) {
        alert("Wall is selected");
      }
      if (ar.selected == true) {
        alert("Arrow is selected");
      }
   }
```

Comment: Your answer adds nothing over the existing answer, which was posted about 45 minutes before yours.

Comment: Yes it does, nobody use the .selected == true or false in all thiese answers

Answer (score -2):

I think you must replace element `='rabbit'` with element `=='rabbit'`

`==` is comparison operator
and `=` is assignment operator

Comment: You haven't added a single thing to your answer of what wasn't in any of the others. You are fishing for reputation

Comment: Why down-votes? Isn't my answer correct? Seriously I think this website is not as good as I thought. Btw, the answer for simple questions must be concise, not like a big essay questions like you people who fish for reputations do. Go and learn some skills before pointing others. +SuperDJ

Comment: Not my downvote, but if the problem is entirely caused by a typo, the question should be closed (since typos almost never help future users).  Note that the incorrect operator is not the only problem with the code here.

Comment: Clearly it's not a typo, he is just confused between assignment and comparison operator it seems and hence I gave him the simplest of the answers without unnecessary stuff as I wasn't fishing for reputation. Kindly check before downvoting.